# Can pinpoint targeting and vital strike be used together?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, actions

Are the feats [vital strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/vital-strike-combat-final/) and [pinpoint targeting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/pinpoint-targeting-combat-final/) be used together?

Vital strike is used on an attack action which is a special action which uses your standard action, so cant be used during a full round action.

Pinpoint targeting is a standard action, but doesnt say its an attack action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**.

You cannot combine the effects of these feats together. Both of them require the use of a standard action, and both explicitly do not modify your attacks in general; they only give you the ability to make one special attack when you have used the action to invoke the feat. Even if you were somehow able to take two standard actions in a round, they are independent of each other; you'd make one vital strike and one pinpoint attack.

Comment: Well nuts, that makes them a whole lot less useful. Hmm.